# Post-installation Apps Running Slow on 18.04 LTS: Discord and Steam

Tags: 18.04, installed-programs

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a second hard drive. Whenever I open up apps I added after system installation (e.g., Discord and Steam), they run super slow, but every program included in the installation runs fine.

FYI: I have 7,127,99 and 2,097,148 of mem and swap respectively; 1,931,468 of which is free with just the Terminal and Firefox open.

How would I fix this?

Comment: Since programs are loaded into RAM before they actually start, where a program comes from is not a factor. Which applications? How much RAM & swap? `free` will tell you.

Comment: The specific programs are Discord and Steam, and I have 7127992 (1931468 of which is free with just the terminal and firefox open.) and 2097148 of mem and swap respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in Discord on Ubuntu (At least at the moment). It uses 100% of the CPU so it will indeed slow things down. I do not know whether it was reported to them or not. I would imagine they know of the problem but don't have a solution yet.

As for Steam, it uses Java. Java is slow to start and run. The games are okay because they run on OpenGL with 3D handled by your video card, but the rest is that slow Java engine...

Most apps coming with Ubuntu are written in a language which compiles to binary. So that runs directly on the CPU. Some OS tools are using python, but that's likely to already be loaded and the python scripts are generally relatively small.

Answer (score 0):

I may be able to help with Steam performance.  Your issue with Steam may be related to lack of GPU Acceleration by default.

**Why GPU Acceleration Matters:**
By default, Steam runs with GPU acceleration disabled on Linux, which can result in extremely slow performance, making it nearly unusable. Enabling GPU acceleration is crucial because it transforms Steam, making it run smoothly as it should have from the start.

**Step-by-Step Guide:** Enabling GPU Acceleration for Steam on Linux

**Initial Sluggish Performance:**
When you first install Steam on Linux, you may notice that it runs extremely slowly. This is because GPU acceleration is disabled by default, causing games, web content, and the Steam interface to perform poorly.

**Open Steam:**
Launch the Steam application on your Linux system.

**Access Steam Settings:**
In the top-left corner of the Steam window, click on "Steam" to open the drop-down menu. From the menu, select "Settings."

**Navigate to User Interface:**
In the Settings window, look for the "Interface" category on the left-hand side. Click on it to reveal the Interface settings.

**Enable GPU Acceleration:**
Under the Interface settings, you will find an option that says "Enable GPU accelerated rendering in web views." Check the box next to this option to enable GPU acceleration.

**Apply Changes:**
After enabling GPU acceleration, make sure to click the "OK" or "Apply" button at the bottom of the Settings window to save your changes.

This solved Steam's poor performance for me. I hope this will be the same for you.